What's the meaning when configuring multi-targeting use TargetFramework.StartsWith in Maui?
I am creating a MAUI project that supporting iOS and Android platforms.
The .csproj of project need to distinguish iOS and Android when using different
type of source.
There is a shared way from official document that Configure filename-based multi-targeting, such as including iOS files/folders as follows:
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net8.0-ios')) != true">
  ...
  <BundleResource Include="Resource\*.png" />
</ItemGroup>

However, there is an another way to include iOS files/folders as follows:
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0-ios'">
    ...
    <MauiImage Include="Resource\*.png" />
</ItemGroup>

The effect of them is different, the first method will crash but the second will not.
I can not understand this. If someone has more information between using them, that will be much appreciated.

The first condition checks if your current TargetFramework's name starts with net8.0-ios where as the second once checks if it is .net7.0-ios or not that's the only difference i see between them, Not sure what you mean by the first one crashes and the second does not, also why do you have .net7 in one condition and .net8 in another not sure!

@FreakyAli Thanks for replying, not concerning about .net 7.0 or 8.0, because we have not changed from .net 7.0 to 8.0 now. The first condition use '!= true', if start with iOS is not true, it should be other target frameworks. Therefore, I have the doubt about the same effect between them.

Oh, I have understanded that, the effect of them maybe the same at the most status.
But the code inside them should be the different, the fist condition != true, then we should remove the include, such as follows:
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net8.0-ios')) != true">
  ...
  <BundleResource remove="Resource\*.png" />
</ItemGroup>

and the effect will be the same with second one.
Thanks for @FreakyAli taking care of this question.
